# Thread on Leg/Ankle

Tags: hanuman

I was recently watching Indian Kushti wrestling and I noticed that a lot of people (males) wear some thread on their ankle. I also have seen a poojari wearing one on his right leg when I visited a temple (In America). I was wondering what the significance of this was, as I though people usually tie thread to their wrists. Could this be related to Lord Hanuman (many Indian wrestlers worship Hanuman)?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Hanuman. Actually, those in wrestling tie it around ankle to avoid navel displacement (which srsly is a big problem & mordern science don't acknowledge this). It happens if the leg is given sudden jerk. Well the thread keeps the nerve ending & vessels tight thus avoidng the former problem. Eg, I tie them on my both toes coz of the same problem of ND. Nxt is becoz, they say it cures leg pains. Also, it is believed that the black thread protects the person from mallice or evileye. Some associate it with Rahu, Ketu or Shani for luck. It depends, y a person wear it.